# Java - Set a "Int" in a textfield

Tags: java, awt

I'd like to set a int in a textfield to represent a ID. This int will be incremented when the user clicks the button Next. I'm using awt. I tried to do this but it gives a error because it expects a string. :( Is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will need to keep an internal `int` variable which you can increment, then update the textfield with the String representation when it's changed. Similarly make sure to update the `int` if the user manually edits the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`public static String String#valueOf(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

One can convert an `int` to a `String` with either

```
int i = 100;
String s2 = String.valueOf(i);
String s1 = "" + i;
```

I believe that `valueof()` is the preferred approach because it can re-use static data for the value.

Comment: FYI `"" + i` is calling `String.valueOf(i)` behind the scenes